# Qual a função do print('\a') no python

Tags: python-3.x

Me disseram que a função `print('\a')` deste código produz um sinal sonoro, mas na hora quando eu executo no pycharm não há nenhum sinal sonoro.

Gostaria de saber pra que serve esta função. E se poderiam me mandar um tipo de lista de funções print, exemplo `print('\n')`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from sys import stdout

from time import sleep

print ('Cronometro regressivo | programador => mmxm')

segundos = int(input('Digite a quantidade de segundos: '))

tempo = timedelta(seconds=segundos)

print ('\n')

while (str(tempo) != '0:00:00'):

    stdout.write("\r%s"%tempo)

    stdout.flush()

    tempo = tempo - timedelta(seconds=1)

    sleep(1)

stdout.write("\r0:00:00")

stdout.flush()

print ('\a')
```

Comment: Tentou executar o código direto no terminal?

Comment: Eu pus esta função no terminal como você sugeriu, mas não ocorreu o sinal sonoro, apenas um ponto azul apareceu na tela.

Answer (score 3):

Isto provavelmente só funciona em alguns terminais porque os desenvolvedores mantém isto por algum interesse ou compatibilidade e claro isto só pode ser executado em terminal, se tentar executar em outro lugar, como pycharm, ele no máximo vai imprimir na saída isto: `<0x07>`

Nos emuladores de terminal geralmente não funciona, mas creio que o `xterm` funcione, dependendo da distro, não posso afirmar por todas, como disse, depende dos desenvolvedores manterem a compatibilidade com isto ou não.

O nome deste caractere é `BEL` (ASCII Bell), o código dele no ASCII é o `7`, então provavelmente seu equivalente em Windows seria o `^G` (o `^` é o escape), mas creio que isto ou dependa do serviço `Beep` ou da placa mãe, imagino que isto tenha vindo em uma época que placas de som não eram comuns em computadores, sim houve tempos assim.

Note que em PCs x86 isto dependia do chip de temporizador de intervalo programável 8254 e provavelmente depois passou a funcionar baseado nas placas de som, o que talvez seja como um serviço para isto, pelo que li em sistemas Windows x64 isto foi removido (no Win10 não sei afirmar, mas provavelmente também foi removido, comentem se encontrem alguma informação sobre isto).

Para concluir, o `\a` vai depender de muitas situações para poder funcionar e se deseja usar isto talvez seja melhor repensar em uma solução mais simples e mais dentro da atualidade, se quer em Python existe esta lib: https://github.com/kindlychung/pybeep, instale usando pip:

```
pip install pybeep
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use:**

```
print("\a") # Python 3
```

ou

```
print "\a"  # Python 2
```

ou **Bash Shell**:

```
echo $'\a'
```

**Obs:** em alguns terminais a campanha pode estar desativada.